# Search documents with parent-child context : Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have the following XML. When I search for city as Bangalore & state as Telegana it should not return any result since the city and state belong to different address elements...

```
XML Document  :
<person>
    <name>Sundeep</name>
    <address>
        <city>Bangalore</city>
        <state>Karnataka</state>
    </address>
    <address>
        <city>Hyderabad</city>
        <state>Telangana</state>
    </address>
</person>
```

> Search for: city=Bangalore & state=Telangana
>
> Current Output : It returns the person document when using below query

```
<search:and-query>
    <search:value-query>
        <search:element name="city"/>
        <search:text>Bangalore</search:text>
    </search:value-query>
    <search:value-query>
        <search:element name="state"/>
        <search:text>Telangana</search:text>            
    </search:value-query>
</search:and-query>
```

Excepted Output: Since both city and state belong to two different
address element it should not return the above document in the result. Any
pointers in solving this issue using REST-API or XQuery ?

Answer (score 2):

I actually just solved this problem earlier today using the /v1/search REST API here: [Marklogic 8 xml search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729537/marklogic-8-xml-search/30731686#30731686)

To use xQuery for a solution this will work just fine for you:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search =
     "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
     at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $options :=
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="address">
      <element-query name="address" ns="" />
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="city">
      <value>
        <element ns="" name="city"/>
      </value>
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="state">
      <value>
        <element ns="" name="state"/>
      </value>
    </constraint>
  </options>

return
  search:search('address:(city:Bangalore AND state:Karnataka)', $options)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot can you please help me with equivalent rest-query ?

Comment: A few footnotes on Rob's suggestion. 1). You don't need to create range indexes for the value queries above on city and state. 2). The easiest way to eliminate false positives for containment is to turn on filtering by adding <search-option>filtered</search-option> to the options. 3). In the REST API, you can either install the query options and send a string query or send a structured query equivalent to the combination of a string query with the query options.

Comment: @ehennum : Thanks for the tip on indexes. I gave <search-option>filtered</search-option> a shot but didn't have any luck getting it to work. I'd be curious to know more. Good point on #3, I'll amend my other answer to include that.

Comment: @RobS. You can set the debug option to true to see the actual query executed.  I don't believe a constraint can tag a parenthetical expression, in which case part of the query would be thrown away or treated as literal text. This kind of query is easier to do with structured search, where search:container-query can specify the address element and contain the city and state value queries. For more about the pros and cons of filtered search, see: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered#id_74746

Comment: @ehennum Is my understanding correct with respect to writing container-query in below syntax  <search:container-query>
 <search:element ns="" name="address"/>    
    <search:and-query>
    <search:value-query>
   <search:element ns="" name="city"/>
   <search:text>Hyderabad</search:text>
  </search:value-query>
  <search:value-query>
   <search:element ns="" name="state"/>
   <search:text>Telagana</search:text>
  </search:value-query>  
     </search:and-query>
  </search:container-query>
 </search:query>

Comment: That looks right to me. You could execute a combined query with that container query in the query part and a search:search-option element of filtered in the options part to eliminate the false positives.